# cakephp auth login always false

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I am working on a simple login application with cake.. Always return false.. why? My code

My AppController code is...
**AppController.php**

```
public $components = array(
        'Session', 'RequestHandler', 'Auth', 'Email'
    );
    public $helpers = array(
        'Session','Time','Text','Number'
    );

    public $titleForLayout = null;
    public $currentUser = array();

    public function beforeFilter() {

        // Configurações específicas para cada prefixo
        if ($this->isPrefix('operador')) {
            $this->layout = 'admin';
        } elseif ($this->isPrefix('user')) {
        }

        // Configurações de login
        $this->_manageAuthConfigs();


        $this->currentUser = $this->Auth->user();
         $this->set('usuario',$this->Auth->user('nome'));
         $this->set('id',$this->Auth->user('id'));


        return parent::beforeFilter();
    }

    public function _forceSecure(){
        $this->redirect('https://'.env('SERVER_NAME').env('REQUEST_URI'));
    }

    // Verifiy that is a prefix
    protected function isPrefix($prefix)
    {
        $params = $this->request->params;
        return isset($params['prefix']) && $params['prefix'] === $prefix;
    }



    private function _manageAuthConfigs() {

       // $this->Auth->authError = 'Área restrita, identifique-se primeiro.';
        $this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller');
        $this->Auth->allow('index', 'info', 'enviar');
        AuthComponent::$sessionKey = 'Auth.User';

        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index',  'user' => true);
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'Obras', 'action' => 'painel');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'index');
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
            'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'User',
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password'=>'password'),
            ),
        );

        if ($this->isPrefix('operador')) {
            $this->layout = 'admin';
            AuthComponent::$sessionKey = 'Auth.Operador';

            $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'operadors', 'action' => 'login', 'operador' => true);
            $this->Auth->loginRedirect =  array('controller' => 'operadors', 'action' => 'Home');
            $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'operadors', 'action' => 'index');
             $this->Auth->deny();
            $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'userModel' => 'Operador',
                    'fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password'=>'password'),
                    ),
                );
            //$this->Auth->allow('index', 'login', 'home');
        } 

      }

      public function isAuthorized($user = null) 
        { 
                return true; 
        }
```

My UsersController code is...
**UsersController.php**

```
public function index(){
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
       if ($this->Auth->login()) {
           $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
             $this->Session->setFlash('<b>Erro!</b> E-mail ou senha inválidos.', 'default', array('class'=>'alert alert-danger'), 'Operador.CCN');
        }
    }
    }
```

**View/User/index.ctp**

```
                                                                <?php echo $this->Session->flash('bad');?>
                                                <?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
                                                <?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
                                                                                            <div class="row">

                                                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                                                        <label>E-mail</label>
                                                                                                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('email', array('class'=>'form-control', 'label'=>false));?>
                                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                                </div>  
                                                                                            </div>
                                                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                                                        <a class="pull-right" id="headerRecover" href="#">Esqueci minha senha</a>
                                                                                                        <label>Senha</label>
                                                                                                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('password', array('class'=>'form-control', 'label'=>false));?>
                                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                                </div>
                                                                                            </div>
                                                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                                                <div class="col-md-6">

                                                                                                </div>
                                                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                                                    <?php echo $this->Form->button(__('Login'), array('class'=>'btn btn-primary pull-right push-bottom')); ?>

                                                                                                </div>
                                                                                            </div>
                                                                                        </form>


                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: are the login credentials correct?

Comment: Yes, Localhost its work but in dreamhost server not.. (sorry my english)